# Tor browser. Unwanted Connect / Configure Question, after network interruption

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

**I am useing Tor Browser.** On first start of browser I got the follow normal question. I selected the "Connect" button and after than the browser worked allways fine.

[image]

Depend on my often unstable dsl connection, i lose some time per day the internet connction. Depend on this the Tor browser ask me in this situation, on every new Tor browser start the same "Connect" or "Configure" question like on first browser start.

[image]

Question: How to prevent me from the "Connect" / "Configure" question after every DSL network error ?

I was looking for a Tor Browser forum, a i didnt find a forum for like this.

On Firefox I have seen one time, its possible to configure some things on "about:config". It can be its possible to disable my problem by about:config.

Does someone know a anything I can search for, a search term or even a known solution ?

THX

Comment: TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG=0 ./start-tor-browser.desktop sounds intresting.
Thats works fine, without the .desktop extension My Tor browse is located on: /home/user/desktop/tor/ I guess i can do now on Terminal: cd /home/user/desktop/tor/ TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG=0 ./start-tor-browser Its possible to write both in one line ? I will try to build me a Link for this for my Ubuntu desktop

Comment: You can use the line `cd /home/user/desktop/tor/ && TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG=0 ./start-tor-browser.desktop`

Comment: THX in advanced !!!

Comment: For my understanding, is TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG=0 a program which is located in the directory /home/user/desktop/tor/ ? But I don't see one with such a name or similar. Or is it a about:config option or something completely different ? Its working fine, a I dont understand what is called there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an 'about:config' option for this (`extensions.torlauncher.prompt_at_startup`), but it should usually already be set to false, and the browser changes this to true automatically as needed.

Instead, you should use the `TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG` environment variable when you start the browser. If you disable it, Tor will connect to the Tor network automatically without prompting. On Linux you can use:

```
TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG=0 tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach
```

I believe it should be similar on Windows on the command line using:

```
set TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG=0
start tor-browser.exe
```

Comment: **The folllow is working fine and prevent me from unwanted additional "Connect" / "Configure" questions:** cd /home/user/desktop/tor/ && TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG=0 ./start-tor-browser **Now i ask me, what are "TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG=0" doing:** * Is this a program which is located in the directory /home/user/desktop/tor/ ? But I don't see one with such a name or similar. But it could be that it is a hidden program. * Or is "TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG=0" an option of ./start-tor-browser.desktop, but I can't find an option with a suitable name using ./start-tor-browser.desktop -help. * So what is actually c

Comment: @Alfred.37, `TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG` is an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Unix). You can find it in the code [here](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-launcher.git/tree/src/modules/tl-util.jsm?id=4f593816e87010cc81a6b924f3f14deac5d4977d#n374).